# Open CV template matching for traffic light recognition

Tags: opencv

I need to recognize the status of traffic signal, Below is the image

[image]

I need to detect the below shape(walking man) and then find the color of it(Green/yellow/red).

**Approach 1:**

1. Pixel extraction with highest RBG values.
2. Clustering to associate pixels to a group based on proximity.
3. Filter the clusters which have other shapes(lights in the cars, or other bright objects in the scene).
4. Find the color of the cluster that has passed filtering.

**Approach 2:**
Use haar classifier to identify this shape.
Once identified find the color of it.

Which of the above approach would be efficient in terms of speed (should work in real time) and processing power. For such a scenario, what is the best approach someone would take.(I am very much new to openCV and image processing).

Comment: Hi, how is the variation of images taken and position of camera? If your camera is relatively fix then it will be very easy.

Comment: A person wearing Google glass will be looking at it..The camera is not fixed

Comment: maybe you're able to predetect things that look like the traffic light box (rectangular) and warp your image so that this region is normalized in size and orientation before you give it to your detector (even stupid template matching might work in that scenario). obviously this method only works in all traffic light boxes look the same =)

Comment: I think that converting to HSV color-space is good for the color recognition. It's robust and not brightness sensetive if you use hue-value. Also add saturation if needed :)

Comment: @ØysteinW.and Micka.. thank you for your inputs.. So can I assume that approach 1 is better for this kind of recognition?

Comment: Do you want to detect this specific traffic light or pedestrian traffic lights in general?

Comment: @diip_thomas pedestrian traffic lights in general..I thought I would start with this one because it is more commonly used

Comment: I agree with @ØysteinW, HSV color-space is much better than HSB. Checkout http://greenrun.io - not as detailed as what you are looking for but does demonstrate the color/position detection. Also check out http://mobile.greenrun.io for current status of an active test sensor.